# warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed

Tags: cuda

I referenced almost all similar questions but did not find an answer. Error checking is recommended by many people, So I tried to use `CHECKED_CALL()` type macro to make the program strong, but my code has encountered two problems:

1. As the title says, I got a warning message, but before I used `#pragma hd_warning_disable`, I got the error message:

   `cuEntityIDBuffer.cu(9): error: identifier "stderr" is undefined in device code`
2. When I compiled the `maintest.cpp`, I got another error:

**EDIT:**

```
 g++ -c maintest.cpp -std=c++11
 cuEntityIDBuffer.h:1:27: fatal error: thrust/reduce.h: No such file or directory
```

However, it works fine when compiling `cuEntityIDBuffer.cu` `cuEntityIDBuffer.h` is also included in this file.
 `nvcc -arch=sm_35 -Xcompiler '-fPIC' -dc cuEntityIDBuffer.cu`

Both `cuEntityIDBuffer.cu` and `maintest.cpp` `#include "cuEntityIDBuffer.h"`, but `maintest.cpp` throws an error, I have no ideas about it.

The code is below:

`cuEntityIDBuffer.h`

```
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER __host__ __device__
#else
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER
#endif

class cuEntityIDBuffer
{
public:
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER cuEntityIDBuffer();
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER cuEntityIDBuffer(unsigned int* buffer);
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER void cuCallBackEntityIDBuffer(unsigned int* buffer);
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER ~cuEntityIDBuffer();
    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER void cuTest();
private:
    size_t buffersize;
    unsigned int* cuBuffer;
};
```

`cuEntityIDBuffer.cu`

```
#include "cuEntityIDBuffer.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma hd_warning_disable
#define nTPB 256
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

__global__ void mykernel(unsigned int* buffer)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
    buffer[idx]++;
    //other things.
}

cuEntityIDBuffer::cuEntityIDBuffer()
{
    buffersize=1024;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&cuBuffer, buffersize * sizeof(unsigned int)));
}

cuEntityIDBuffer::cuEntityIDBuffer(unsigned int* buffer)
{
    buffersize=1024;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&cuBuffer, buffersize * sizeof(unsigned int)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(cuBuffer,buffer,buffersize*sizeof(unsigned int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
}

void cuEntityIDBuffer::cuCallBackEntityIDBuffer(unsigned int* buffer)
{
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(buffer,cuBuffer,buffersize*sizeof(unsigned int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
}

cuEntityIDBuffer::~cuEntityIDBuffer()
{
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree((cuBuffer)));
}

void cuEntityIDBuffer::cuTest()
{
    mykernel<<<((buffersize+nTPB-1)/nTPB),nTPB>>>(cuBuffer);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
}
```

`maintest.cpp`

```
#include "cuEntityIDBuffer.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    unsigned int *h_buf;
    h_buf=malloc(1024*sizeof(unsigned int));
    cuEntityIDBuffer d_buf(h_buf);
    d_buf.cuTest();
    d_buf.cuCallBackEntityIDBuffer(h_buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it the wrong way that I used the `CHECKED_CALL()` type macro or is there a problem with my code organization? any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile the main with gcc? You must use nvcc and use a .cu extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your methods are defined as `__host__` and `__device`, which means they will be compiled once for CPU and once for the device. I don't see any big issue for the CPU version. However, you have two problems for the device version:

- `cuEntityIDBuffer.cu(9): error: identifier "stderr" is undefined in device code` is very clear, you're trying to use the CPU variable `stderr` in device code.
- `warning: calling a __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed` is the same kind of problem: without any of `__host__`, `__device__` or `__global__` attribute, symbols are implicitly set to `__host__`, which means in your case that the device version of your methods is trying to use `gpuAssert` which is only on CPU side.

For `cuEntityIDBuffer.h:1:27: fatal error: thrust/reduce.h: No such file or directory`, as @Talonmies pointed out, any Thrust code has to be built using nvcc.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I seem to understand the first problems you mentioned above, so, if I  want to print the error message, where should I put the `gpuAssert` code to compile correctly?  The second problem may not be as you described becasue the `cuEntityIDBuffer.cu` file can be compiled with NVCC correctly, which also include `cuEntityIDBuffer.h`.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Try to use `printf` instead of `fprintf` when in device code. You can check the `__CUDA_ARCH__` macro for that.
I'm not sure to understand the the second part of your comment. Can you edit your question and specify what error appears at which time?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's what I said, you're using two different compilers, so make sure they are using the same include paths so g++ can also resolve Thrust includes.

Comment: @RobinThoni: Any thrust code *must* be compiled with nvcc.